# How to create a child Tab.Screen in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have four Tab screens:
Home    Gallery    New-turn    My-Account

Homepage.js

```
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
          let iconName;

          if (route.name === HomePageTitle) {
            iconName = focused ? "md-home" : "ios-home";
          } else if (route.name === TurnsPageTitle) {
            iconName = focused ? "md-calendar" : "ios-calendar";
          } else if (route.name === GalleryPageTitle) {
            iconName = focused ? "ios-images" : "ios-images";
          } else if (route.name === MyAccountTitle) {
            iconName = focused ? "md-contact" : "ios-contact";
          }

          // You can return any component that you like here!
          return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
        },
      })}
      tabBarOptions={{
        activeTintColor: "#ff8da1",
        inactiveTintColor: "gray",

        style: {
          backgroundColor: "white",
        },
      }}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name={HomePageTitle}
        component={Home}
        options={{ title: "Home" }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name={GalleryPageTitle}
        component={Images}
        options={{ title: "Gallery" }}
      />

      <Tab.Screen name={TurnsPageTitle} options={{ title: "New-turn" }}>
        {(props) => (
          <TurnType
            {...props}
            component={TurnType}
            serverDate={currentDate}
            plusMonth={plusMonth}
            phone={phone}
            name={name}
          />
        )}
      </Tab.Screen>

      

      <Tab.Screen name={MyAccountTitle} options={{ title: "MyAccount" }}>
        {(props) => (
          <MyAccount
            {...props}
            component={MyAccount}
            name={name}
            phone={phone}
          />
        )}
      </Tab.Screen>
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
```

After I press New-turn there is a button that lets you navigate to another Stack Screen (in app.js)
`<Stack.Screen name='Calendars' component={Calendars} />`

I navigate it by using this code:

```
navigation.replace("Calendars", {
                      serverDate: global.serverDate,
                      plusMonth: global.plusMonth,
                      phone: global.phone,
                      turnUnits: item.type_units,
                      turnTypeName: item.type_name,
                      navigation: navigation,
                    });
```

When I do this my bottom tabs just disappear when I navigate to Calendars. I need a way to navigate to Calendars without this tab being visible in bottom tabs and then to navigate back to New-turn screen when I press a button for example. How to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using react-navigation v5+ and the Calender Screen is under New-turn tab's stack navigaor, the below should help

```
navigation.navigate('New-turn', { screen: 'Calendars' });
```

Comment: It is not under New-turn tab's stack navigator, how do I make Calendars a child of New-turn? I just don't want to see the Calendars in the bottom tabs but I want to have access to it from the tab navigator when I navigate to it, and also still see the other bottom tabs icons when I am inside Calendars

Comment: Create a stack navigator with all screens related to New-turn, and then in Tab.screen assign that stack navigator for New-turn tab